# automake failed while switching git branches

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make, automake

I'm trying to compile C++ automake project:

```
./autogen.sh;./configure;
```

On the main branch is working as expected. On my feature branch I received the following error:

```
./configure: line 20576: syntax error near unexpected token `visibility'
./configure: line 20576: `AX_GCC_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE(visibility)'
```

***EDIT***
When I'm running `make` I'm receiving this error:

```
make: *** [Makefile:724: config.status] Error 2
```

Comment: What is the difference between the main branch and your branch in regards to the configuration scripts? What does those differences tell you?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the configure script are identical. I even try to merge the `main` branch to the `feature` branch.

Comment: If the string `AX_GCC_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE` is appearing in your configure script, then you have problems early on.  That is an `m4` macro that should have been expanded when the configure script was made.  This is not a problem with `automake`, but with `autoconf`.

Comment: You probably need to copy the macro definition from the autoconf archive into a local `m4` directory and specify that directory in `configure.ac` if it's not already there.

Comment: If something works in the repositories master branch, and doesnät in your, then there's something you have made in your branch, or something you have forgotten. First of all check *all* the differences between the branches in your repository tool. Then if nothing obvious stands out check the directory structures and possible subprojects (if supported by the VCS) which might have been forgotten.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the problem indeed was with autoconf and m4 files. Thanks!!

Comment: The `configure.ac` file should `m4_pattern_forbid([AX_GCC_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE])dnl` before relying on `AX_GCC_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE`. That would have made `autoreconf` (called from `autogen.sh`) fail instead of generating a broken `configure` file.